# How to get the default style for a control that isn't posted on MSDN?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I'm overriding several Silverlight styles so that the focused visual state color is configurable. I've managed to get most of it done, but I'm having an issue with the `DatePicker` control. The default style for the `DatePicker` itself can be found [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278067%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but the actualy control that gets focus is a customized textbox called a `DatePickerTextBox`. This is the style I need to override, but I can't find it anywhere. How would I go about getting the style for a control that isn't on MSDN? Everything I've found always says "go look on MSDN for it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS 2012 or VS 2013 in the Document Outline window while viewing your xaml you should be able to right click on the control in question and get the control template for that control..

Comment: Oh hey you're right! That's an awesome feature I never knew about, thanks.